# Unset Variable Using condition or If

Tags: symbols, condition

**Using `Condition`**

```
<< Notation`
Notation`ClearNotations[];
Notation`Symbolize[NotationTemplateTag[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Tau]\), \(^\)]\)], 
 WorkingForm -> TraditionalForm]
(*Overscript[\[Tau], ^] =1*)
ValueQ[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Tau]\), \(^\)]\)]

\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Tau]\), \(^\)]\) =. /; ValueQ[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Tau]\), \(^\)]\)];

\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Tau]\), \(^\)]\)
```

[image]

If `ValueQ[]` return `False`, why it still complains `Unset "Assignment on OverHat for Overscript[\[Tau], ^] not found"`

I just want to clear specific values of the [OverHat](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OverHat.html) or Subscript

When it runs again, it complains `Symbolize Warning: The box structure attempting to be symbolized` , even though I have added `Notation'ClearNotations[];`
[image]

**Using `If`**

[image]

`OverHat[\[Rho]]` Unset fails in `If` expression, but succeeds in `OverHat[\[Rho]]=.`

Comment: Would `If[ValueQ[t], t = .]` work? Is it mandatory for you to use `Condition`?

Comment: No, I just want to clear the values of  `OverHat[v]`. `If` works. Why Condition does not work?

Comment: `Condition` is a pattern test function, and you have no pattern in your expression.

Comment: @MarcoB When `If` acts on a `List`, it does not work. `ValueQ` does not  jump over `#=.`

Comment: Yes, because once the symbols that have a value are in the list, they get evaluated to their values, so it is the values there passes to your function, and not the symbol names themselves. You hit on a pretty hard thing to do in MMA. However, if you can write a list of the symbols, then instead just write `Clear[symbol1, symbol2, ...]`. If the symbol does have a value, it will be cleared; if it doesn't, nothing will happen to it. So you would accomplish the same result.